# Am I allowed to send http request in req.get?

Tags: node.js, express

Okay probably a weird question but usually when you have code like this

```
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
 response.render('pages/index');
});
```

You use mongoDB and grab the relevant data in you database to return but what if I wanted to make an api call to another service for the data?

I'm using the request library (https://github.com/request/request#streaming)

and so far my code looks like this

```
request = require('request');
....
....
app.get( '/examplePage', function( request, response ) {
  request("http://www.google.com", function(error, response, body) {
   console.log(body);
  });
});
```

But I get a "TypeError: object is not a function" which is weird because I just copied and pasted the code provided as an example on their github page. So I just changed request to request.get (since the default is a GET but I just explicitly use the get method) but I don't get a response back or the Google HTML isn't returning.

So basically I'm not even sure if I'm even allowed to use a request method call in an app.get method which I'm assuming might be the problem?

Comment: Yes, that is allowed. However, you have a logic problem. What do you think `request` refers to inside your function? the `request` var defined outside your function, or the `request` parameter defined inside your function.

Comment: the request param defined inside my function, gotcha thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request` is not what you think it is inside the `app.get` function. You should change it like so:

```
request = require('request');
....
....
app.get( '/examplePage', function( req, res) {
  request("http://www.google.com", function(error, r, body) {
   console.log(body);
  });
});
```

so that you aren't covering any variables you have previously set. When you are attempting to use the `request` module it is referencing the request parameter it received in the `app.get` invocation which is not a function.

Comment: ohhh....I see the conflict in the variables. Thanks, it worked :) need to wait a while to accept as answer

Answer (score 2):

You have two objects called `request` in your code, the **request** module and the **request** from the route in the http call, You can update your code to something like:

```
var request = require('request')
...
app.get('/example', function (req, res) {
  request("http://googl.com", function (err, response, body) {
    console.log(body)
  })
})
```

Also take into account the `res` and `response` objects can't have the same name, if you do so the latter will be taken into account depending on the context you are using it.